# comparing selected items of 2 listboxes

Tags: if-statement, listbox, compare

I'm having trouble comparing selected items of 2 listboxes. The following if statement never executes:

```
 if (lbVisitorTeam.SelectedValue == lbHomeTeam.SelectedValue)
```

Comment: Can you share more details about your development environment?

Comment: C#, Visual Studio 2012, SQL Server 2012

Comment: They both represent ValueMember in the same table in a database

Answer (score 0):

Check that the selected items are identical. You need to ensure differences in leading and trailing spaces aren't causing problems, or that they have different casing. You can use Trim() to get around the first issue, and use Compare() with ignore case to get around the second.